# How to find out to which 'user' I should add 'scc'?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, privileges, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to run `elasticsearch` container in my openshift project.

I got errors:

> Privileged containers are not allowed capabilities.add: Invalid value:
>   "IPC_LOCK": capability may not be added capabilities.add: Invalid
>   value: "SYS_RESOURCE": capability may not be added

I've found out that you need to add `privileged scc` to user account (or create own dedicated one).

I've tried to follow docu https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/admin_guide/manage_scc.html where the following commands are given:

```
oc create serviceaccount mysvcacct -n myproject
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:myproject:mysvcacct
```

However, no single clue is given what is `mysvcacct` and why it is called `mysvcacct`.

Because my project is called `logging`, I've tried the following:

```
oc create serviceaccount logging -n logging
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:logging:logging
```

but it didn't change anything. I keep getting the same error.

What I'm missing there? What name should I use instead of `mysvcacct`?

Comment: You have to update the ``serviceAccountName`` of the deployment or deployment config to use that service account. Check first whether it may already be running under non default service account though. Run ``oc explain dc.spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName`` for details of setting.

Comment: Also see https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-can-i-enable-an-image-to-run-as-a-set-user-id.html for related information.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton is it allowed to specify spec.serviceAccountName during creation time (in initial yaml)?

Comment: Yes, you can set ``spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName`` in deployment when creating it. That is the preferred way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, I introduce the example of `yaml` format.

- You can modify the `ServiceAccount` name using `oc patch dc/your-deploymentConfigName` cmd as follows.

```
# oc patch dc/elasticsearch --patch '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccountName": "logging"}}}}'
```

- Or using `oc edit dc/your-deploymentConfigName`, take a look around `serviceAccountName`.

```
# oc edit dc/elasticsearch
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/test/...
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: logging
      serviceAccountName: logging
```